# 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused and looking for someone to point me in the right direction;

**The route I'm trying to get to is /admin/login**

I have the following AdminController file;

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    // Login
    function login(){
        return view('backend.login');
    }

function submit_login(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $userCheck=Admin::where(['username'=>$request->username,'password'=>$request->password])->count();
    if($userCheck>0){
        return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }else{
        
        return redirect('admin/login')->with('error','Invalid username/password!!');
    }
}

function dashboard(){
    return 'Dashboard';
}


}
```

and this is my web routes file;

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class,'home']);

Route::get('/admin/login', [AdminController::class,'login']);

Route::get('/admin/login', [AdminController::class,'submit_login']);

Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class,'Dashboard']);
```

Can anyone identify why the too many redirects are happening?

I'm getting a simple in chrome

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

TIA

EDIT: I was being silly, should've done post not get for the second route.

Comment: which route throw this error?

Comment: I've updated the queston but /admin/login

Comment: The second `/admin/login` route should be post instead of get.

Comment: That did something... but now I'm getting Undefined offset: 1.

Comment: you cant use same URI pattern `/admin/login` with same method `get`, this is not the solution but its a bug

Comment: You're probably accessing an array key that doesn't exist in your view. As an aside: given how you're checking the password, it looks like you're saving it as plain text in your database. That should be changed.

Comment: Thank you all for the kind and helpful comments. Solution to my issue was post not get and the latter issue I had a syntax error in my blade file (was just missing a space)